# In Ruby, is there a Binding available that is created at the time of the exception available during the rescue?

Tags: ruby, exception, binding, rescue

The precise pain point I'm having is I am parsing a list of files.  Each file has multiple lines.  When something goes wrong, I'd like to print out such things as the current file name, the current line number, the current line, and some other interesting variables and then exit in most cases since the error will be in my code that needs to be enhanced.

Most of the variables are local to the `#each` blocks that are nested.  There are multiple places something could go wrong.

What I'd like to do is just have one global `begin`, `rescue`, `end` block and within the `rescue` have a `Binding` available to me so I could dig out the various variables I'm interested in printing out.

This seems like a rather obvious `Ruby` type thing so I find it odd that I'm the first guy who would want such a thing.  Yet, I don't see any `Binding` or closure concepts in the exception handling parts of Ruby's documentation.  Usually this means I'm radically misusing the concepts of the language.

Comment: Add some code to your question, please. While you can call Binding#new anytime you want, deeply nested loops are generally a code smell, so this seems like a potential X/Y problem. If what you want isn't available in the rightward assignment of your exception handler, you're probably creating needless complexity rather than using the right objects and methods in a testable way.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the easiest way is to define all variables that you want to track before your `begin ... rescue ... end block`.

You can then easily access them within the rescue block:

```
variable = 0
another_variable = 0
begin
    3.times do |a|
        variable = a
        5.times do |b|
            another_variable = b
            if a == 2 and b == 4
                raise KeyError
            end
        end
    end
    at_exit do
        puts binding.eval 'variable'
        puts binding.eval 'another_variable'
    end
rescue KeyError
    puts variable
    puts another_variable
end
```

But if you want to get last `binding` before exception occurs - your solution is to use TracePoint:
https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/TracePoint.html

This allows u to track bindings where local variable that u need is defined and then get last of them. Of course, if you will use this method it will make your program a little bit slower. The example of usage:

```
last_binding = nil
trace = TracePoint.new(:b_return) do |tp|
  last_binding = tp.binding if tp.binding.local_variable_defined?('variable')
end

trace.enable

begin
    3.times do |a|
        variable = a
        5.times do |b|
            another_variable = b
            if a == 2 and b == 4
                raise KeyError
            end
        end
    end
    at_exit do
        puts binding.eval 'variable'
        puts binding.eval 'another_variable'
    end
rescue KeyError
    trace.disable
    puts last_binding.eval 'another_variable'
end
```

(The best event for u to track is `b_return` - it occurs after each block's ending, so this will make your tracking time-optimal)

Comment: Thank you.  I knew I could use global variables ... which to me is just yucky.  Tracepoint sounds like a trace facility.  Exceptions have zero run time overhead but tracing does.  Tracing also has other subtle, hard to diagnose side effects.  Sounds like the real answer to my question is "no".  I think I'll file a feature on the Ruby bug site.